# Python Use code again and again

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, function

I have a piece of code which getting data from excel sheet using python XLRD and automate it via selenium

```
row = sheet1.row(0)  # 1st row
Gname = row[0].value                
Lname = row[2].value
profession = row[3].value
email = row[4].value
phone = row[5].value
add = row[6].value
user = row[7].value
write(Gname)
press(TAB)
write(Gname)
press(TAB)
write(Lname)
press(TAB)
write(profession)
press(TAB)
write(profession)
press(TAB)
write(email)
press(TAB)
write(phone)
press(TAB)
write(add)
press(TAB)
write(user)
press(TAB)
write(Gname+"@123")
click("add parents")
click("Add a parents")
```

I need to run this code again and again around 550 times but with incremental rows

```
row = sheet1.row(0)  # 1st row
```

it need to be `sheet1.row(1), sheet1.row(2), sheet1.row(3)` and so on....

Please tell me how I can automate or use this code **with different row variable**

Comment: Use the magic of loops; `for` for a preference. You should really consider reading a basic Python tutorial before posting a question like this.

Comment: Agree, it felt like a trick question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import xlrd

excel_sheet = xlrd.open_workbook("teacher.xlsx")
sheet1= excel_sheet.sheet_by_name('parents')

```
for i in range(0, sheet1.nrows):        
    row = sheet1.row_slice(i)        
    Gname = row[0].value        
    Fname = row[1].value        
    Lname = row[2].value

print Gname
print Fname
print Lname
```

that work fine now code fetching 0 to ∞ data from rows.

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this?

```
for i in range(0, 550):
     row = sheet1.row(i)
```

I Python 2 you can use `xrange` instead of `range`, for lazy evaluation of the range sequence.

You can read more on `for` loops in the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)